# How to inject parameter value into bean during test execution?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

In a `Car` class constructor Im using `@Value` annotation to inject value as an parameter.

```
@Service
public class Car {
  
   public Car(@Value("${app.fabric.kafka.topics.sometopic}") final String topic) {
   }
   ...    
}
```

`GarageService` class declares and uses `Car` instance.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GarageService {
    
    private @NonNull final Car; 
 ...
}
```

In a `GarageServiceTest` class I use `@InjectMock` to instantiate testing object and `@Mock` to inject another instance.

```
@ContextConfiguration
public class GarageServiceTest {
    @Mock private CarService carService; 
    @InjectMock private GarageService;
    ...
}
```

The test in this class gives an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error when creating bean 'GarageService' defined in file [.../GarageService.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1, 
...
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BenCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'Car' defined in file [.../Car.class]: Unexpected exception during bean 
creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 
app.fabric.kafka.topics.sometopic' in value "${app.fabric.kafka.topics.sometopic}".
```

The question how to resolve this exception? My understanding is that in that test class I need to find a way to inject `${app.fabric.kafka.topics.sometopic}"` value into bean `Car'.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a _unit_ test or a more comprehensive Spring-based functional test? You're mixing styles.

Comment: This is only high level extract from much more complex code. Its unit test. Its testing the method in a class that has dependency of another instance.

Comment: So? One of the major advantages of using constructor injection is that you can just call `new ServiceUnderTest(mockDependency, string)`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're running a test using the Spring extension. This means that Spring will initialize an `ApplicationContext` for your tests. Apparently, during that initialization, the  `app.fabric.kafka.topics.sometopic` is unavailable for some reason.

This initialization has nothing to do with Mockito's `@Mock`/`@InjectMocks` annotations. If you want to test the `GarageService` *Spring bean*, with `CarService` being mocked, try the following:

```
public class GarageServiceTest {
    @MockBean private CarService carService; 
    @Autowired private GarageService;
    ...
}
```

If you want a unit test instead, in which `GarageService` is created as a regular object, just don't use `@RunWih(SpringRunner.class)`/`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` for this particular test.

In case you face the same issue in other tests, in which `CarService` is **not** supposed to be mocked, use `@TestPropertySource(properties = "app.fabric.kafka.topics.sometopic=<whatever works>")` or `@SpringBootTest(properties = "app.fabric.kafka.topics.sometopic=<whatever works>")` if using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid huge spring context:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Car {
    @Value("${app.fabric.kafka.topics.sometopic}")
    private String topic;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class GarageService {
    private final Car car;
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class dd {
    String topic = "topic";
    @Mock Car car;
    @InjectMocks GarageService garageService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(car.getTopic()).thenReturn(topic);
        System.out.println(car.getTopic()); // topic
    }
}
```